# Why is an implicit operator static?

Tags: c#

I notice that an implicit operator is required to be called static but it actually is not really static at all... How come the implicit operator cannot be accessed statically but it can be accessed through an instance. This is the complete opposite of static. Suppose I wanted a static static implicit operator so that I could implicitly convert the static states of a class.

For example

```
a = new b(); // implicitly converts b to a.
a = b(); // implicitly convert the static states of b to a.
```

So for example b is a non-static class because it has a form but for all intents and purposes it is static and all instances are sharing the same information so I want to implicitly convert the class' static internals.

I will try to go into more detail of my example since Jeff thinks it makes no sense.

`class b` displays a dialog form, but it saves all the information entered into static variables. This is because the instances of b are only to display the dialog form and the data entered is one logical block of data(there is only one logical instance of the data entered). All the static variables fit directly into `class a` and so I can seamlessly convert the static variables in `b` to an instance of `a class`, however I would like to use implicit operator for this task instead of having a separate method. But it laments me that I cannot have an **actual** *static* implicit operator. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the word static and I am only using it in terms of how it works with methods and classes.

Comment: All user defined operators are static. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense, nor does your question.

Comment: A standard implicit conversion behaves like an invisible non-static method. I want an implicit conversion that behaves like an invisible static method. Jeff what exactly does not make sense? I have static variables. The class is only non-static because of displaying the form. But all the data is saved in static variables. I want to implicitly convert the static variables statically but the regular behavior of the implicit operator behaves like a non-static method.

Comment: @CodeCamper You can cast all the static variables one by one. If you want to cast a whole static class, you can't, it is static, you can't have an instantiation of it. If you want to have an instantiation of it and play around with it, then you didn't want it to be static after all.

Comment: Patashu I want it to be static because there will only logically be one instance of it and never more than one instance. I am only making it non-static for the sake of displaying the form. I want the form to implicitly convert to a string.

Comment: This is not a good reason to use static. You said the word instance yourself. If there's an instance, it's not a good practice to make it static.

Comment: Suppose I will only have 1 instance and only one instance. A function for example which is used multiple times but does store data but only one instance of data. Never shall there be more than one instance of the data. Isn't that a good reason?

Comment: Ilya Kogan I want to be able to do exactly this
`string x = InputBox` or
`string x = InputBox()`
with no new keyword and no dots and no delegates. I want a class which only purpose is to display an InputBox without using the standard method way.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to override the `ToString` method on your `InputBox` class. I'd rethink the need to make it a static class. At a pinch you might want to use the Singleton pattern to ensure there is only ever one instance of it (but I personally would avoid that too if possible).

Comment: The truth is I want to make a class behave like a function. I can do it using the new keyword in conjunction with the implicit operator but I can't do it without the new keyword?

Comment: You can still access the static fields of your class inside a static implicit conversion operator. Hard to offer better advice without understanding the *why* of your need to make a class behave like a function.

Comment: I want to thank everyone for these great answers, definitely thumbs up to everyone giving a little piece of the puzzle. Ergwun I guess what I wanted was to be able to implicitly convert a static instance(whatever you call this) of a class as opposed to a new instance of a class. You and p.s.w.g. gave a way to do this by making a fake static class which actually does work perfectly. I just wish I could make it syntactically look like a VB6 function. Such as using a delegate so I don't have to type the dot-instance.

Comment: @CodeCamper Assuming this is some experiment in esoteric syntax mangling, I've updated my second answer to show you how you could force that syntax usage, but I would in no way recommend you actually do that!

Comment: `esoteric syntax mangling` finally someone who understands me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an `operator` was not `static`, it could not handle `null` operands.

This applies equally to the case of an implicit conversion operator:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int x)
    {
        this.X = x;
    }

    public int X { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator int(MyClass operand)
    {
        if (operand == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }    
        return operand.X;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass x = null;
        int y = x; // What instance would a non-static operator use here?
    }
}
```

Comment: The `int y = x` would use the static instance of the class. The instance which was created when the program compiled which stores the static variables.

Comment: @Ergwun: Good catch! I didn't think about this as a reason for forcing all operators to be static.

Comment: @CodeCamper There's no such thing as a "static instance of a class", unless you are talking about an instance of a class held in a static field or property (e.g. like in a singleton). I think you are going to need to clarify your question.

Comment: Ergwun when I say static instance I am referring to where the static variables and methods are stored. I would like to implicitly convert these static objects. I know how to do it with methods but I just learned about how I can implicitly convert and it is a real shame I can't implicitly convert static things without the use of a secondary instance.

Comment: @CodeCamper In this answer I've tried to answer your headline question of "Why is an implicit operator static?" I've posted a second answer to have a go at helping with your underlying problem, as far as I can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

No operator works on the 'static state' of a class (except possibly `typeof`). In other words it's not possible to do anything like this:

```
var result = System.Int32 + System.Int32;
```

Operators only work on *instances* of a class.

```
int a = ..., b = ...;
var result = a + b;
```

All operators are necessarily static, so there's no need to disambiguate between 'normal static' operators and 'static static' operators.

You might consider using a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Member { get; set; }

    private static Foo instance = new Foo();
    public static Foo Instance { get { return instance; } }

    private Foo()
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo.Member;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
int a = Foo.Instance;
```

Comment: So I cannot implicitly convert a static class even if logically it could be implicitly converted?

Comment: No. You'd have to make a method like `static MyClass ToMyClass()`.

Comment: How does `typeof` work? The only reason I am asking this question is because I am trying to see if I can make C# behave like a functional programming language. Right now I have a solution that uses the `new` keyword but it is silly because I have no reason for the new keyword other than to display a form which will always be the same form anyway.

Comment: `typeof` is a language feature. It's built into C#, and you can't override it or mimic it's behavior in a custom operator. I'm really not sure how this would make C# behave more like a functional language at all, but see my update for another solution.

Comment: typeof is calculated in compile time.

Comment: I want to see if I can make classes behave like functions. Right now I can using the `new` keyword. Now I am just trying to subtract the `new` part when it is not necessary.

Comment: @CodeCamper It sounds like you want a factory pattern, just create a static method that returns a new instance of the type. [more info here](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fee817667.aspx&ei=0mq5UfWCBM2aiQfrx4GIBw&usg=AFQjCNE1ngKi6eePymsheLCf1qBIx_s_Fw&sig2=j5X5J-vmX_xcRO77PthwDw&bvm=bv.47883778,d.aGc)

Comment: alexw thank you for the link. I think you may be on to something here. I read a bit but I will definitely read it over more later. All I know right now is I want to make a class a function because I just want to see if I can create a new design pattern just for personal fun(I will use it to make my programs). Right now if I use the new keyword in conjunction with the implicit keyword I can make a class behave exactly like a method/function. My objective with this question was to see if there was a way to subtract the new word.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, all operator definitions are static, see for instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx

-Binary operator definitions, of course, because it would be arbitrary to declare one or the other to be `this`.

-Unary operator definitions, to match the theme of binary operator definitions being static.

It is just convention that it is done this way.

Comment: The static implicit operator behaves exactly like an invisible non-static method. There is no way to make an implicit operator behave like an invisible static method?

Comment: @CodeCamper You keep saying 'implicit operator'. What I am trying to point out is that all custom operator definitions, binary and unary, are declared as static in C#, nothing special about the implciit ones.

Comment: Patashu, I would like to create an implicit conversion that is static. I don't understand what makes operator static. But I know one thing, it behaves exactly like a non-static method. Which to me is contradictory. I cannot access static things directly from an instance of a class, yet I can only access my static implicit from the complete opposite; an instance of a class. I understand what I am trying to do is apparently rare since people just use the regular work around(s) but I would really like to implicitly convert a static class.

Comment: @CodeCamper If you want to convert the variables of a static class into a string, why not just write a static method on the static class that returns a string and call that? If I am off base here, you need to edit your question and put in the REAL question you actually want an answer to, with code examples etc, so I can look at it.

Comment: Actually this is really an abstract sort of question but I am really using it in a real program. First I made an InputBox and it worked fine. Then I was trying to emulate what InputBox looks like in VB6. I was taught about implicit operator which allowed me to use the new keyword to make it behave exactly like this. Then I realized all I had to do was subtract the new keyword because I will have only 1 instance of the form going visible and invisible. So I am literally trying to implicitly convert a static instance of a class because I hate dots.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a second answer from me, trying to guess at your underlying problem (instead of answering the question in the title, as I did in my first answer):

From the editted question and comments, it looks like you are trying to:

1. ensure that there is only a single instance of an `InputBox` class.
2. Convert data in the input box class to a `string`.

I'd make sure that you really need to *enforce* only a single instance of the `InputBox` class, but if that requirement is well founded then you could do something like this, using the Singleton pattern, and overriding the `ToString` instance method.:

```
class InputBox
{
   static InputBox Instance = new InputBox();

   int someNumber;

   string someText;

   private InputBox()
   {
   }

   // ...    

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return someNumber.ToString() + " " + someText;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
string result = InputBox.Instance.ToString();
```

***Addendum:***

If it's *really* all about the syntax you want to use, you could add a delegate like this:

```
        // Please don't really do this ;)
        Func<string> InputBox = () => MyNamespace.InputBox.Instance.ToString();
```

And then use it like this:

```
        string result = InputBox();
```

But anyone reading your code would cry ;)

Comment: This made me laugh! I'm totally going to do this. Now the next problem. I WISH I could automate this in all of my classes. Should I just generate a #region list of all my functions and copy and paste would that be the easiest way?

Comment: I am in total denial that I cannot have my VB modules in C# and I need a way to satisfy my blood lust. I have fallen in love with semicolons but also am in love with global functions. The lack of global functions no matter how not-important they are is very frustrating to me. Now I need a way to automate the delegates for all my projects quickly. One giant static class and a bunch of delegates so I don't have to use the name of the static class. It is kind of ridiculous that I can't just have global functions.

Comment: Fall in love with inversion of control and testability instead, and forget about your global functions - they were never right for you. You'll be happier in the long run </preach>.

Comment: I hate how every function must *belong*, it is like communism. Some functions are just meant to be libertarians. I'm just going to post in the VB section how to add semicolons to VB if I can't have my global variables haha. Besides I miss having range compatible switch statements and with statements.